# error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@angular-devkit%2fcore: self signed certificate in certificate chain"

Tags: angularjs

getting ssl cerficate error for yarn bootstrap command
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFzIZ.png)

tried to some suggested steps but not got any solution

tried to run `yarn config set strict-ssl false --global` to set false.

Does anybody know a way of disabling the self-signed certificate verification?

For **yarn,** a very similar error occurs:

Answer (score 0):

It is checking for ssl certificate, which seems you dont have.
by default its strictssl:true.

make it false by using below first command & follow other two commands to yarn bootstarp

```
yarn config set strict-ssl false --global

mkdir node_modules

yarn bootstrap
```

**Note:** Make sure Expected version "^14.20.0 || ^16.13.0 || >=18.10.0".